# Bot keeps requesting Azure AppService

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, bots

Our company has a web site running on Azure, and we are getting 3000 requests per day from a Bot (or bots) on non existing URL's. We return 410 as resultcode, but the but keeps 'calling' the website with the same request.

What can we do about this?

The Azure logging shows : operation_SyntheticSource: Bot

And client_IP: 0.0.0.0

and from different locations like:

- Singapore
- USA - Virginia - Ashburn
- USA - Virginia - Boydton
- USA - Washington - Seatle
- Ireland
- France
- Netherlands - Limburg - Heerlen

Comment: It is recommended to parse the hostname requested by the bot, add an application gateway, and manually add rules to reject the request of the bot.

Comment: It is recommended to add a filter on the webapp program to filter frequent requests for the same parameters.